# Build SSIS projects in a docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2013, ssis

Currently we use devenv to compile SSIS projects and to create an ispac file.

I'm trying to acheive the same using a docker container. I tried installing VS 2017 in docker using commandline but running devenv just hangs and does not produce any output.

Different to the above issue, our acutal SSIS projects are built on legacy VS2013 and haven't been moved to 2017 yet. Is there a way of achieving this in docker container? Does anyone have experience of this?

Comment: With regards to your second question, you need to be aware of what your deployment SQL Server version is as there are some constraints around this. At a guess your devenv is maybe hanging because it's waiting for some input? A developer login perhaps?

Comment: Hi Nick, The SQL server version is 2014. The SSIS works fine perfectly and at the moment we wont be changing the way it is hosted. Just trying to move the build to a container.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand this is not currently supported and from Microsoft side there are no plans yet to [support SSIS](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35208061-add-ssis-to-the-sql-server-docker-image) running on Docker.

On Docker side, the issue to support SSIS is still [open as well](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/213)